# Changing ecplise target directory for relative path resolutions

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have a particular directory named tool, which contains many directories and files. I have a large eclipse project in java. The exported jar file of the project is placed inside the tool directory. During the runtime the jar file uses many direcotires and files inside the tool folder using relative path. So if there is a directory inside tool name data and a file named conf.txt inside that directory the jar file will access it as data/conf.txt. Now if I want to run the project using the command line argument run configuration in eclipse how can I set up eclipse so that it will always look into the tools folder for relative path resolutions? The project is huge and I cannot simply change all the relative path strings with corresponding absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify command line arguments here:

From the menu bar Go to Run>Run Configurations...>Arguments tab

Hope this was helpful and sufficient.

Comment: Hi my question was not about that. I know how to run command line arguments. I just want eclipse to look in a particular directory to resolve relative paths.

Comment: Why do you want to configure path in eclipse? In that case your application will be dependent on eclipse. You can have the path configured in some property file and read the path from that file instead.

Comment: Why my application will be dependent on eclipse? It is relative path. The original jar file will be placed in that folder in the distribution, and it will use relative path. I want eclipse just to use that folder, it does not mean I am changing the code in my project. So the application wont be dependent on eclipse.